# Audio html tag for live radio

Tags: html, reactjs, audio, live-streaming, internet-radio

I need the audio player to be in real time.

Current problem: When I give the command audio.pause() and then audio.play() the player returns from where it left off and not live.

Can someone help me? I'm using react with vite.

Actual code:

```html
import { useState } from "react";

import {
  FaPlay,
  FaStop,
  FaVolumeUp,
  FaVolumeDown,
  FaVolumeOff,
  FaVolumeMute,
} from "react-icons/fa";

export function Player() {
  const [radioRunning, setRadioRunning] = useState(false);

  const playRadio = () => {
    const radio = document.getElementById("player") as HTMLAudioElement;
    radio.scrollTo()
    radioRunning ? radio.pause() : radio.play();
    setRadioRunning(!radioRunning);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <audio loop={false} id="player">
        <source
          src="<my-radio-stream-link>"
          type='audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.5"'
        />
        <source
          src="<my-radio-stream-link>"
          type="audio/aacp"
        />
        <span>Your browser dont support that element.</span>
      </audio>
      <div className="w-full flex justify-center gap-8 fixed bottom-0 py-2 bg-zinc-800">
        <button className="p-2">
          <FaVolumeUp className="w-5 h-5 mx-auto" />
        </button>
        <button className="p-4 -translate-y-11 rounded-full" onClick={playRadio}>
          {radioRunning ? (
            <FaStop className="w-10 h-10" />
          ) : (
            <FaPlay className="w-10 h-10" />
          )}
        </button>
        <button className="p-2">
          <FaVolumeUp className="w-5 h-5 mx-auto" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Maybe just set volume to 0 instead of stopping audio ?

Comment: thanks for the tip, but the idea was for the volume to remain the same and just pause the audio and then be able to return at the same volume, .muted and .play() solved my problem.

const radio = document.getElementById("player") as HTMLAudioElement;
if(!radioRunning) {
radio.volume = volume / 100;
radio.play();
}
radio.muted = radioRunning;
setRadioRunning(!radioRunning);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your `playRadio` function is way to mute instead of stoping:

```
 const playRadio = () => {
    const radio = document.getElementById("player");
    radio.scrollTo()

    if(!radioRunning) radio.play()
    radio.muted = radioRunning;

    setRadioRunning(!radioRunning);
  };
```